# ets can find the record but can't delete it

Tags: erlang, elixir, in-memory-database, ets

i have a simple problem. `ets:lookup()` can find the record but `ets:delete()` gives `badarg` error.

```
case ets:lookup(Connections, Next) of
    [] ->
         case ets:lookup(Connections, Prev) of
             [{Network, Node, Address}]->
                  print_ets_table(Connections),
                  ets:delete(Connections, Network), -> this gives error
                  ets:insert(Connections, {Next, Node, Address}),
                  Next;
             _ ->
                  % Report
                  Prev
                  end;
    _ ->
        % Report
          Prev
         end;
```

print_ets_table(Connections):

```
[{<<134,176,18,190,115,242,102,213>>,
  {sslsocket,{gen_tcp,#Port<0.6>,tls_connection,
                      [{option_tracker,<0.110.0>},
                       {session_tickets_tracker,disabled},
                       {session_id_tracker,<0.111.0>}]},
             [<0.114.0>,<0.113.0>]},
  <<127,0,0,1>>}]
```

and the error

```
{badarg,[{ets,delete,
              [#Ref<0.3551319967.1683357697.51087>,
               <<134,176,18,190,115,242,102,213>>],
              [{error_info,#{cause => access,module => erl_stdlib_errors}}]}
```

`Network` is binary type data and
this is how table was defined

```
Connections = ets:new(connections, [set])
```

i read the ets doc and ask GPT but could not find the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ets:new/2` creates a protected table, which means the owner process can read and write the table but other processes can only read it. If you want any process to be able to delete table entries, you can make the table `public` instead:

```erlang
ets:new(connections, [set, public]).
```